# Painting pixels images in Java

Tags: java, swing, pixel, graphics2d, paintcomponent

Which method is the best way to create a pixel image with java.
Say, I want to create a pixel image with the dimensions 200x200 which are 40.000 pixels in total. How can I create a pixel from a random color and render it at a given position on a JFrame.

I tried to create a own component which just creates pixel but it seems that this is not very performant if I create such a pixel a 250.000 times with a for-loop and add each instance to a JPanels layout.

```
class Pixel extends JComponent {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(getRandomColor());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You do not need to create a class for this. Java already has the excellent [BufferedImage](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) class that does exactly what you need. Here is some pseudo-code:

```
int w = 10;
int h = 10;
int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;

BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, type);

int color = 255; // RGBA value, each component in a byte

for(int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        image.setRGB(x, y, color);
    }
}

// Do something with image
```

Comment: 1:1, does not work when trying to put this onto a swing pane. using the same code with an image from `ImageIO.read()`, it does. so there's something wrong with the code here, though I'm not sure what

Answer (score 6):

The key here is the `Canvas` class.  It is the standard `Component` that allows arbitrary draw operations.  In order to use it, you must subclass the `Canvas` class and override the `paint(Graphics g)` method, then loop through each pixel and draw your random color.  The following code should work:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class PixelCanvas extends Canvas {
    private static final int WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 400;
    private static final Random random = new Random();

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        for(int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
                g.setColor(randomColor());
                g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
            }
        }
    }

    private Color randomColor() {
        return new Color(random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.add(new PixelCanvas());

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The generated image looks like this:

[image: Noise Image]

Comment: Be wary of mixing `Canvas` and `JFrame`; also consider `new Color(random.nextInt(), true)`.

Comment: Same can be achieved by instantiating a `Frame` instead of `JFrame` to avoid weird mixings.

Comment: Still, calling `drawLine` sounds like overkill when you already know you only need a single pixel.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably want to create a `BufferedImage` of the size you want, and use `img.setRGB(x, y, getRandomColor())` to create a bunch of random pixels.  Then you could render the whole image wherever you want it.